# Getting shock from the current flowing through metal surfaces of R-pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I have a working Raspberry pi 3 which i generally connect to my TV through HDMI cable.
But after connecting it to The Monitor through a **HDMI to VGA** cable there a current flowing through all the metal surfaces of the R-pi3 which is giving shock.

Though there was no such kind of condition using the TV.
The reason is obviously the cable converter.[image: cable converter looks like this]

Can this harm my R-pi?What steps should one take to protect from such harms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was expecting the question to be if this could be harmful to *you*!  The answer to that is potentially yes. This current flowing is a sign of a problem in your wiring, which should be fixed or replaced.

The Pi, as a secondary consideration, could also be damaged for the same reason.  Whatever is causing this stray current may be unstable and cause a surge.  Your Pi also cannot handle high voltage, so its circuits are exposed to anything near 120 V or 240 V (depending on your location), it will be fried.